# How can I programmatically import configuration?

Tags: 8, configuration

I try to import specific configuration. I use this :

```
$config_path = config_get_config_directory(CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY);
$source = new FileStorage($config_path);

$config_storage = \Drupal::service('config.storage');
$config_factory = \Drupal::configFactory();
$uuid_service = \Drupal::service('uuid');

$configs = [
  'field.storage.config_pages.field_areas',
  'field.field.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.field_areas',
  'core.entity_form_display.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.default',
  'core.entity_view_display.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.default',
];

$config_storage->write('field.storage.config_pages.field_areas', $source->read('field.storage.config_pages.field_areas'));
$config_storage->write('field.field.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.field_areas', $source->read('field.field.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.field_areas'));
$config_storage->write('core.entity_form_display.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.default', $source->read('core.entity_form_display.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.default'));
$config_storage->write('core.entity_view_display.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.default', $source->read('core.entity_view_display.config_pages.configuration_implantation_page.default'));
```

If the field is created, the table is not created.

How to create the tables associated?

Comment: I believe the system will create the table when you first try to save some data to it

Comment: Try to add `$config_storage->save();`

Comment: Take a look https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/programmatically-importing-drupal-8-field-configurations

Comment: @berramou, post this as an answer. The important thing is not simply store config, but create and save config entities and so run CRUD methods/hooks like [FieldStorageConfig::preSave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldStorageConfig.php/function/FieldStorageConfig%3A%3ApreSave/8.7.x)

Answer (score 2):

You should save the config like `$config_storage->save();` :
As @4K4 mentioned :

> The important thing is not simply store config, but create and save config entities and so run CRUD methods/hooks like https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldStorageConfig.php/function/FieldStorageConfig%3A%3ApreSave/8.7.x

Comment: Getting `Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Config\CachedStorage::save()` error when I try to use `$config_storage->save()`